# Power Query Data Refersh

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel-services, office-web-apps, refresh, excel-web-access-webpart

I used power query in the MS Excel to import data from SharePoint online List, and create a dashboard by using the data of that list. Everything work perfectly when I used that excel on my desktop, but when I upload the excel into my SharePoint online environment and open the file into excel online then data refresh got stuck and is show  below error [image]

any suggestion how to resolve that. I checked the excel online features at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/excel-online-service-description.aspx , it stated that the too (below image)

[image]